# How to remove item in json_array in myslq

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I has 1 problem: I used json_remove & json_search but it's not working for result of json_search in mysql 8.0

**Database:** books table.

```
|public_unit_ids|
'[5630, 5631]'
```

**Query: **

```
select  
replace(json_search(REGEXP_REPLACE(public_unit_ids, '(5630|5631)', '""'), 'all', ''), '"', '') as new_js_replace,
json_remove(public_unit_ids, replace(json_search(REGEXP_REPLACE(public_unit_ids, '(5630|5631)', '""'), 'one', ''), '"', '')) as new_js_remove from books
```

**Result:**

| new_js_search | new_js_remove |
| --- | --- |
| '["$[0]", "$[1]"]' | '[5631, 5632]' |

**Expected:** remove 5630 and 5631

| new_js_search | new_js_remove |
| --- | --- |
| '["$[0]", "$[1]"]' | '[5632]' |

Comment: Do you need remove elements from JSON array by their values simply? If so then (#1) how the values to be removed are provided (CSV? JSON array? else?)? (#2) What is exact MySQL version? (#3) Does separate values in source JSON array are unique?

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that JSON_SEARCH() can only search for strings, not integers (see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90085).

Here's another solution.

Given a sample JSON array:

```
mysql> set @j = '[5630, 5631, 5632]';
```

The JSON_TABLE() function maps array elements into rows:

```
mysql> select j.* from json_table(@j, '$[*]' columns (n int path '$')) as j;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 5630 |
| 5631 |
| 5632 |
+------+
```

Now you can use a conventional `WHERE` clause to filter these rows.

```
mysql> select j.* from json_table(@j, '$[*]' columns (n int path '$')) as j where j.n not in (5630,5631);
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 5632 |
+------+
```

The result can be re-aggregated into a JSON array with `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

```
mysql> select json_arrayagg(j.n) as new_j from json_table(@j, '$[*]' columns (n int path '$')) as j where j.n not in (5630,5631); 
+--------+
| new_j  |
+--------+
| [5632] |
+--------+
```

I show this as multiple steps only to explain how it works. You don't need to do all the steps, only the last one.